# How to get JSON data from attributes that start with # or @ in Typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am working with a specific API that returns a JSON that looks like the below sample.

[image]

I want to get both values that contain the #text and @attr but I get error messages in typescript when I try to get the values.

Comment: What is the error exactly? What is the code you have where you access this property? Please provide a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please don't [use images for code, data structures or log files](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9078341)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using,

```
album[0]["@attr"]
album[0]["artist"]["#text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey for JSON you can use get details by its attribute name in it and it's the same for all-weather it starts with @ or # it will be the same.

See below code to get the value of your specified key:

**Sample JSON:**

```
{
    "weeklyalbumchart": {
        "album": [
            {
                "artist": {
                    "mbid": "data",
                    "#text": "Flying Lotus"
                },
                "mbid": "data",
                "url": "",
                "name": "",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "1"
                },
                "playcount": "21"
            },
            {
                "artist": {
                    "mbid": "data",
                    "#text": "Flying Lotus"
                },
                "mbid": "data",
                "url": "",
                "name": "",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "1"
                },
                "playcount": "21"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Read JSON:**

```
@attr ===> json["weeklyalbumchart"]["album"][0]["@attr"]

#text ===> json["weeklyalbumchart"]["album"][0]["artist"]["#text"]
```

Hope this will help you to understand it.